Reference in inline-block default data
I'm using Layout Builder. In one of the components I use the webform reference field, in order to reduce duplication of webforms I created variants and added a custom select widget to choose between those variants. But default submission data that is used for the first block directly influences those that are under it, maybe due to the same webform but different variants. I need to be able to set different default submission data in my specific case. Did someone face such an issue before?
Short variant of question - got problem with use of 2 variants of the same webform on same component page, how to fix this?
